# Export assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I have created a npm project, in which I am using typescript configuration (tsconfig.json).

In one .ts file, I have code such as below:

```
export = function loginToLCSteps() {
    this.setDefaultTimeout(30 * 1000);
    let stage = serenity.callToStageFor({
        actor: (name) => Actor.named('James').whoCan(BrowseTheWeb.using(protractor.browser))
    });

    this.Given(/^that Doctor is on Login screen$/, function () {
        return stage.theActorCalled('James').attemptsTo(
            AccessLifecare.called()
        );
    });

    this.When(/^he enters credentials and click on Login button$/, function () {
        return stage.theActorCalled('James').attemptsTo(
            Login.called()
          );
      });

      this.Then(/^he should be navigate to Role and Care Unit selection screen$/, function () {
        return stage.theActorCalled('James').attemptsTo(
            Wait.until(SelectRoleAndUnitPage.selectRoleAndUnitLabel, Is.visible()),
        );
      });
};
```

tsconfig.json has module system as "commonjs".

`"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
    .....`

The above code works with "**commonjs**" module loader.
However, I want the module loader to be "**es2015**".
Changing the module system to "**es2015**", gives below error in Visual Studio Code on the `export = function loginToLCSteps()` line:

**Export assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'export default' or another module format instead. ts(1203)**

The above code works on few of my peer machines.

I installed latest version of node, npm, Typescript however no success.

Comment: "*Consider using 'export default' or another module format instead.*" is quite on point.

Comment: Using 'export default' starts giving me different run-time error => "Unexpected token {".
There are few imports on top of that .ts file.

Comment: How exactly did you try to use it? What are you transpiling it to, and in what environment do you run it when you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but maybe this can solve the problem:

```
export default ()= function loginToLCSteps() {
```

instead of

```
export = function loginToLCSteps() {
```

or

```
export default {}= () ={
```

or

```
export loginToLCSteps = () =>{
```

Comment: Could use some references to discuss why.